# .clone() create multiple copies

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").clone().appendTo("body");
    });
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

</body>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").clone().appendTo("body");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

this code produce clones of paragraph, but the number of clones grow exponentially like on first click it create 1 copy on second click create 2 clones and so on , how to fix it so it create one copy each time, and how to assign new ids to each new element created dynamically.

Comment: For the first time your body has only 2 p tags. You clone and append it to the body. Now your body has 4 p tags. If you search through the body, you will get all 4 p tags. If you clone now, 4 tags are cloned. After you append, now you are left with 8 tags in the body. The question is, do you want to consider all the p tags in the body on the click event or only the specific 2 p tags?

Comment: Hi @Ahtisham Shahid, if any of the answers solved your problem you should accept it. This will help other users who have the same issue to find a fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because the second time `$("p")` will match, and clone, 4 paragraphs, the second time 8 and so on. You need to do something to "mark" the original ones or the copies. For instance you can mark the "new" items with a css class and filter them, like I did in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/kb0k7nrx/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p:not(.copy)").clone().addClass('copy').appendTo("body");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div p").clone().appendTo("body");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>

<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing in there to help the OP understand what he was doing wrong and what's the fix

Answer (score 0):

Use any class to get the paragraph and append to body. Do not use tag selector which will return all tag available in the page.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $(".para").clone().appendTo("body");
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p class="para">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p class="para">This is another paragraph.</p>

    <button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This doesn't clone **all** paragraphs, only the first.

Comment: Edited answer please check

Answer (score 0):

Give the desired p-Tag a Class-Tag.

```
<p class="foo">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

and Change your jQuery to this

```
$('.foo:last').clone().insertAfter('.foo:last');
```

This will copy the last copied p-Tag and insert it after the last copied p-Tag.

Example:

```js
$("#copy").click(function() {
  $('.foo:last').clone().insertAfter('.foo:last');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="copy">copy</button>
<p class="foo">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

You can Access the Items then by using

```
$('.foo').eq(n).html();
```

.eq(n) gives you the n-th Element of the Class. So you probably wont Need an extra ID.

Answer (score 0):

"p" will select all p elements without restriction, so jQuery will find all paragraph elements inclusively. This is poor performance and will select too much, as you mentioned a second button click has more than expected p elements.

Let's isolate your p elements by wrapping them in an HTML container.

```
<section id="cloneSource">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</section>
```

Update your jQuery to select the container including the paragraphs inside

```
$("#cloneSource").clone().appendTo("body"); // without new IDs
```

For best performance you want to edit the HTML content virtually before placing in the DOM.

```
$("#cloneSource").clone().attr("id", "newId").appendTo("body");
```

Resulting body element

```
<section id="cloneSource">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</section>

<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

<section id="newId">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</section>
```